# What's the best way to switch on union types in Typescript? For example number | string

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-conversion

Suppose I have the following class:

```
export class Complex {

/**
 * Representation of a complex number
 *
 * @param _re
 * @param _im
 */
constructor(private _re: number, private _im: number = 0) {

}

/** implementation details truncated **/
}
```

Now I want to write the following function:

```
function add(z1: Complex | number, z2: Complex | number): Complex {
   if (/** z1 is number **/) {
        z1 = new Complex(z1)
   }
   if (/** z2 is number **/) {
        z2 = new Complex(z2)
   }
   return z1.add(z2)
}
```

What's the cleanest and most idiomatic way to write this in typescript?

Comment: This has nothing to do with TypeScript. The `if` condition is evaluated at runtime. The TypeScript typings are removed at transpile time. This is only JavaScript.

Comment: @jabaa Given that it's TypeScript code, it seems to have *something* to do with TypeScript.

Comment: Well, TypeScript needs to narrow down the types before `z1.add(z2)` can compile, so it does have something to do with the behavior of TypeScript.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, this question has something to do with TypeScript. It has something to do with Microsoft, Linux or Mac, because it runs on a computer and it has something to do with C++ because the browser is written in C++. Your answer proves it. The missing code snippets are pure JavaScript, because the type of the value can only be evaluated at runtime with JavaScript.

Comment: @jabaa No, it has to do with TypeScript in the usual way; the question is presumably about how to write the code so that it works at runtime *and* so that the compiler understands what you're doing well enough to type check it.  I mean, I didn't ask the question, so I can't speak authoritatively.  But given that [`typeof` type guarding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards) is a documented feature of TypeScript, and it applies to this question, it would be very strange if it turns out that this question has nothing to do with TypeScript.

Comment: `z1.add(z2)` being "unable to compile" is specific to TS. In this case, JS will just let it be (no syntax error)

Comment: @jcalz The OP is asking about the check. They're only asking about the code snippet inside the `if` condition. That makes me assume they already know about the type guards. They don't want to cast the type. The check, the code in question, is pure JavaScript.

Comment: It seems we're at an impasse and further discussion is unlikely to resolve it.

Comment: The title is misleading, though, as there is no `number | string` in the code. And then, the method (directly using typeof check) works for this example, but does not work if the union consists of e.g. instances of two different classes.

Comment: To clarify, the reason this is a typescript question is that I want the type checking protection that the typescript compiler provides. I am well aware that I can cast everything to 'any' and write javascript and ignore types. That's why this isn't a javascript question per se.

Comment: You specifically asked for the checks in the `if` conditions. You can use pure JavaScript because TypeScript is smart enough to understand it at transpile time. You don't need any TypeScript-specific code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to do this given your code template is to use a [`typeof` type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards) as follows:

```
function add(z1: Complex | number, z2: Complex | number): Complex {
  if (typeof z1 === "number") {
    z1 = new Complex(z1);
  }
  if (typeof z2 === "number") {
    z2 = new Complex(z2);
  }
  return z1.add(z2)
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwMIHsC2AHCIAHvAN4BQ88uMAlgG5QAuCA+nANwVW0PPws1snSmEwA7ZIxgBXMI0wwAFGxAAueGOnYARiBgAafoID86zTr0BKYfCjBgisOqx4ChS85z4inAL5kyADNpMTkacVt7RQAvAEZPVyJ4AB8NLV0DeGiAJgTvYlTzDI8MLzdSLhpA+EVGAE9cEExquPgAXg74ACIivS7LCspKVraNEAB3UsTCGNjrLn9KKpr6xuas7PbOnvS+gfIhjfaxyZd8mOz5ykX4OEZpGDEs2IA6OwccyzJ-AODQxnCT3eAEEIMxHkwQLM8uVCrtMjkYUk4RYYCUzuUDohxJJEMcYkiCmlUeiykk2gA+LiUVZNFpbUY7VFdeDGE5Tc7RAbqaI2O4PJ5gWaWN5RIWfeY-IA)